# How do I display my array map alphabetically?

Tags: c++

So I've been trying to find ways to make my array map display in alphabetical order but I couldn't really grasp the idea on how to

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
int count[256] = { 0 };
string sen;

    cin >> sen;
    
        for (auto c : sen)
            ++count[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)];
    


for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    if (count[i])
        cout << static_cast<char>(i) << " = " << count[i] << ", ";
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++i) {`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ only if the `count`s for those characters are `!= 0`. The user is not likely to be typing in unprintable characters

Comment: @Remy Oh, yes. I overlooked the `if` statement there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using characters as array indexes.  So simply loop through the array from characters `a..z`, `A..Z`, `0..9`, etc to display the counts in your desired order, eg:

```cpp
int count[256] = {};
string sen;

cin >> sen;
    
for (auto c : sen)
    ++count[static_cast<unsigned char>(c)];
    
for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; ++i)
{
    if (count[i])
        cout << static_cast<char>(i) << " = " << count[i] << ", ";
}

for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; ++i)
{
    if (count[i])
        cout << static_cast<char>(i) << " = " << count[i] << ", ";
}

for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; ++i)
{
    if (count[i])
        cout << static_cast<char>(i) << " = " << count[i] << ", ";
}

// display any other character ranges as desired, eg:
// for (int i = '\0'; i < '0'; ++i)
// for (int i = ':'; i < 'A'; ++i)
// for (int i = '['; i < 'a'; ++i)
// for (int i = '{'; i < 256; ++i)
// and so on...
```

Otherwise, consider using a `std::map<char, int>` instead, and then you can simply iterate its element pairs as-is, since it automatically orders them by key value for you (or you can use a custom `Compare` to order them however you want):

```cpp
#include <map>

std::map<char, int> count;
string sen;

cin >> sen;
    
for (auto c : sen)
    ++count[c];
    
for (auto &elem : count)
{
    cout << elem.first << " = " << elem.second << ", ";
}
```

Comment: Please don't showcase ignoring all non-ASCII-7 characters...

Comment: @DevSolar That would fall under the `...` section in the 1st example. And the code is only reading 8-bit characters, so there aren't many non-ASCII characters to deal with.

Comment: 127 of them, to be exact... your second example is much better. Not good, but better.

Comment: @DevSolar yes, but they are outside the ASCII range, and so they are very charset-dependent, how many of them do you really expect users to type in? Most useful non-ASCII characters are actually outside the Extended ASCII range, so they would be > 255 anyway.  But whatever.

Comment: Björn Günthers from München would like to differ...

Comment: Again, `char` values 127..255 are charset-dependent. `ö` is Unicode U+00F6, `ü` is Unicode U+00FC. They are not guaranteed to be `char` values `0xF6` and `0xFC` in every charset (for example, in most Windows-125x other than 1252 and 1254). When you start dealing with non-ASCII characters, it is best not to use `char` strings for them at all, unless you are dealing with UTF-8.

Comment: No offense intended, but you are dodging the issue. Keeping on with showing people this "`'a'` to `'z'`" approach 1) leaves them unaware of the issues involved, and 2) does not teach them about available means to solve them correctly. It is unfortunate that the C++ standard still does not provide full Unicode support, but that's no grounds to go on assuming that all the world is ASCII-7 either. And that's not even going into EBCDIC and its non-continuous encoding for 'a' through 'z'...